# Chamisha Ushloshim Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

Who knows three hundred thirty five?

חמישה ושלושים ושלוש מאות - מי יודע?‏

The traditional Passover song "Echad - mi yodeya" implies a possible presupposition that there is a Jewish significance to be found for each natural number. Accordingly, there is an ongoing series on Mi Yodeya that is attempting to unearth significant Judaism facts about each number, in sequence.

What significant Judaism facts are there about the number 335? The more significant within Judaism and the more intrinsically dependent on the value 335, the stronger the answer. Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

It would be highly appreciated if you refrained from using lazy gematrias. They are not needed.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I do not understand the phrase, "They are not needed."

Comment: The last line of posts in this series usually contains a pun on at least one lazy gematria instance of the number in question. I added one to this one and the last one.

Comment: @IsaacMoses What is the pun?

Comment: There are two permutations of the three letters which trivially, in gematria, represent the number at hand, both of which relate to one of the words of my addendum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sefer [Chazon L'Moed](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_38636_1.pdf) on the last verses of Daniel, in one of his calculations, calculated that the end of the exile would be in the year 5665.  He understood this to also be hinted to in Hashem's telling Avraham that his children would be in exile for 400 years, which, based on verses in the end of Daniel, he understood to be 400 Sabbatical years.  He completes his count of 400 Sabbatical years with **335** during the final exile, in the 2345 years from the exile of Yehoyakim until the year 5665.

Comment: See also the *P'sikta Zutrasa* (*B'reishis* 49:10, s.v. שילה), who decomposes the 1,335 "days" in [*Daniel* 12:12](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3412.htm#12) into 1,000 and 335.