# Shisha Ushloshim Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

Who knows three hundred thirty six?

ששה ושלושים ושלוש מאות - מי יודע?‏

The traditional Passover song "Echad - mi yodeya" implies a possible presupposition that there is a Jewish significance to be found for each natural number. Accordingly, there is an ongoing series on Mi Yodeya that is attempting to unearth significant Judaism facts about each number, in sequence.

What significant Judaism facts are there about the number 336? The more significant within Judaism and the more intrinsically dependent on the value 336, the stronger the answer. Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Please refrain from providing lazy gematrias.  They are, without question, not wanted.

Comment: why do you think that the Passover song implies presupposition that there is a Jewish significance to be found in each natural number?

Comment: @EinbertAlshtein If not, why would anyone ask "Who knows eight?"

Comment: @EinbertAlshtein It's just the post-facto justification for a very long-standing series here on Mi Yodeya.  If you want to downvote this one, I suppose you should go downvote the past 15 or so posts in this series...

Comment: @IsaacMoses - Who knows 8 definitely implies knowledge about 8. Why does it imply anything about 114,233,228?

Comment: @EinbertAlshtein What's so special about 8? But perhaps you'll argue that that's why the song stops at 13: because there's something special about those numbers but not about all the subsequent numbers. Allow me to demonstrate that that's not the case: [there's something special about 14 also](/q/762).

Comment: There are some reports whose full text I cannot see online that indicate that 336 Jewish soldiers died in the U.S. Civil War. I don't know whether that's Union soldiers or both sides', nor can I vouch for the accuracy of the number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 354 days in a "normal" Jewish Year and 18 days when we complete Hallel (in Israel) according to the Talmud.

354-18 = 336.

Thus, 336 days in a normal year in which we don't say a full hallel.

Comment: I sense an answer for http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60290/759 as well...

Comment: Could also do 354-21 if you keep two days yom tov, and swap 354 for 355 and 353 depending on the length of the year.  Between these two substitutions, you get anything in the range 332-337.  :)

Answer (score 2):

[Rabbi Benjamin Blech](https://books.google.com/books?id=huJRVbHvWMkC&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=336+purim&source=bl&ots=LOx-ow5s5r&sig=oxnlLmoU3YGQrXTZxTI-hGNEOo8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=stqbVaalH8j0-QH2kYhw&ved=0CDcQ6AEwBzgK#v=onepage&q=336%20purim&f=false) says as follows. The hero on Purim was Esther. פורים = 336 and 336 is also equal to לאשה as we are grateful to a woman for this miracle, Queen Esther.