# Shiv'a Ushloshim Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred thirty seven?

### שבעה ושלושים ושלוש מאות - מי יודע?‏

The traditional Passover song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea) implies a possible presupposition that there is a Jewish significance to be found for each [natural number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). Accordingly, there is an [ongoing series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) on Mi Yodeya that is attempting to unearth significant Judaism facts about each number, in sequence.

What significant Judaism facts are there about the number 337? The more significant within Judaism and the more intrinsically dependent on the value 337, the stronger the answer. Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Answers that are cheap like lazy *gematria* are not preferred.

Comment: This question is in scope according to my rules for the Jewish Stackexchange, but it would seem no one else's...

Comment: That implication is quite a stretch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entire *Halel* is recited eighteen days a year in Israel: the first day of *Pesach*, the day of *Shavuos*, the seven days of *Sukos*, the day of *Sh'mini Atzeres*, and the eight days of *Chanuka*. Thus, in a non-leap year in which *Marcheshvan* has thirty days, so the year has 355 days, there are 337 days the complete *Halel* is not said in Israel.

Comment: ...in communities which don't recite the entire Halel on Yemei Atzmaut and Yerushalayim.

Answer (score 1):

Half the number of sheep/goats captured from *Midyan* was 337.5 thousand. [Numbers 31](http://chabad.org/9959):36, :43.

Answer (score -1):

337 - Year of death of Constantine who summoned the Council of Nicaea, which caused the definite break of cristianity from judaisim.

Answer (score -1):

The number of perakim learned to complete the modern bavli daf yomi cycle.

Comment: How do you know this?

Comment: I added the perakim in seder moed, Nashim, nezikin, kodshim, plus maseches brachos and nidda, minus the six prakim of avos. Numbers were sourced from this post http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18892/list-of-number-of-mishnayos-by-chapter-masechta

Comment: Are you going to post in http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60931/shisha-ushloshim-ushlosh-meyot-mi-yodeya tomorrow?